# Sencha Touch 2: Add NestedList inside TabPanel

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I try to insert a NestedList in a TabPanel, but I get an empty list, the content is not displayed. How to make visible this Neestedlist

Code I tried:

Thank you in advance for your help

```
Ext.define('ListItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: ['text']
    }
});

var treeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'ListItem',
    defaultRootProperty: 'items',
    root: {
        items: [
            {
                text: 'Drinks',
                items: [
                    {
                        text: 'Water',
                        items: [
                            { text: 'Still', leaf: true },
                            { text: 'Sparkling', leaf: true }
                        ]
                    },
                    { text: 'Soda', leaf: true }
                ]
            },
            {
                text: 'Snacks',
                items: [
                    { text: 'Nuts', leaf: true },
                    { text: 'Pretzels', leaf: true },
                    { text: 'Wasabi Peas', leaf: true  }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.NestedList', {
    fullscreen: true,
    store: treeStore
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Sencha',

    launch: function() {
        // The whole app UI lives in this tab panel
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            requires: ['Ext.List', 'Ext.dataview.List', 'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'],
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            fullscreen: true,
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

            items: [
                // This is the recent blogs page. It uses a tree store to load its data from blog.json.
                {
                    xtype: 'nestedlist',
                    title: 'Blog',
                    iconCls: 'star',
                    cls: 'blog',
                    displayField: 'title',
                    store: treeStore
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your provided code, in the Nested List you are creating, you are setting a **displayfield** property with a value of "title". Therefore the list is trying to use the "title" field from your model, which does not exist. Either change your store data to use "title" instead of "text", or remove the **displayField** property (as the default is already "text").